# Bullnose vs square edge stair treads

Tags: wood, flooring, woodworking, stairs

I've been looking around the internet, and I've seen quite a few stair renovations using common boards with a square edge rather than bull nose stair treads.

Is there a difference between the two beside looks?

Code, wear and tear? The common boards are definitely less expensive and have a larger stock to choose appealing boards from when I buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The building code does address the width, profile, and the rounding of the treads.

From the 2009 IBC:

> **R311.5.3.3 Profile.** The radius of curvature at the leading edge of the tread shall be no greater than 9/16 inch (14 mm).

I believe the reason for rounding the leading edge of the tread with wood is to reduce the likelihood of splintering. Also, standard soft pine building lumber is more likely to warp or be damaged with use than a hardwood stair tread.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: For clarity - a larger radius is more rounded. Hence a code specified maximum radius does not preclude having no radius at all, i.e. a square edge would not violate the quoted clause.

Comment: But the square edge is going to get roughed up quickly on a stair tread.

Comment: And really square edged don't hold a finish or take well to carpeting or other tread covers. Finally, for us foot-draggers, they may also catch a brushed heel, which a rounded edge is less likely to do.

Comment: @AndyT:  Mathematically, the larger the radius, the less rounded.  An infinite radius circle is a straight line... Now are the drafters of building codes mathematically literate??

Comment: @DJohnM - Yes, the drafters are mathematically literate. An infinite radius, causing a straight line, would mean that the tread had only a horizontal plane, *and no vertical face to it at all*. The drafters have precluded this - sensible people. I will grant you that "more rounded" and "less rounded" are not exact terms, perhaps you would prefer "a larger radius means a larger part of the tread is curved; hence a maximum radius does not preclude having no radius at all, i.e. no part of the tread being curved, i.e. a square edge"?

Comment: @DJohnM In this case the radius refers to the relationship between two lines that are perpendicular to each other where the radius would be zero. As you cut the corner between the two lines you increase the radius going from zero to infinity and hence make the corner more rounded not less.

Comment: The tread has a given thickness.  If the radius is 1/2 the thickness, the bullnose will be a semi-circle centered where the bullnose meets the rest of the board.  If the radius is larger, the bullnose will be an arc that covers less than a semi-circle.  If the radius is smaller, it is impossible for the bullnose to cover the edge of the tread.  Treads are typically 5/4" lumber, so 9/16" would be approx. a semi-circle.  The rule is irrelevant for a thinner tread, but impossible for a thicker tread.  So it must be the wrong terminology.  It must refer to the protrusion, not the radius.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I believe the terminology is correct.  You can easily have a 3/4 inch radius on a 3/4 inch tread - it will make a quarter circle (but will not be code compliant).  You can also have a 1/8 inch radius on a 2 inch tread - it will be rounded over at the top, and then straight.  It doesn’t appear that the code cares whether it’s a true semi-circle, just that the radius isn’t too large which probably increases the chance of slipping on the step.

Comment: Square edge can have advantages of less slipping and in industrial facilities are usually covered with a metal and or non skid surface to reduce slips and falls, the last plant I worked at had many of the buildings updated to square tress because of the number of slips and falls in the older buildings with rounded trends.